# How do I make this texture visible as a PNG?

Tags: texturing, export, transparency, uv-image-editor

I'm trying to export this model's textures from Blender, and I can do all of them fine except for the Eye texture.  When I export it, it is just a blank PNG. I don't know how to make it visible in the UV editor or as a PNG. It's only visible on the model. I tried baking, exporting, messing around with settings but I can't find anything.

[image]

Comment: Yes you're right but why does it not display in the UV Editor? Maybe he should share his file, at least the eyes objects

Comment: @moonboots I don't know, I deleted my comment because my suggestion cannot work if the image does not show up :D  Can you pack a procedural texture as image within blender?